# How are map keys interpreted in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to create a map literal with the keys determined from a random function:

```
user=> {(str (rand-int 5)) "hello" (str (rand-int 5)) "goodbye"}                                            
IllegalArgumentException Duplicate key: (str (rand-int 5))  clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap.createWithCheck (PersistentArrayMap.java:71)
```

whereas

```
user=> {(str (rand-int 5)) "hello" (str (rand-int 6)) "goodbye"}    
{"4" "hello", "2" "goodbye"}
```

The Reader appears to be treating the key as an un-evaluated list.

I can't find any details about this in the documentation. Is there anyone who can help me understand this a little more?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/YVELqu6gAQQ/mZoEG0yg37QJ

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. Combined together they answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Walking through the source of Clojure compiler I've found the following:

1. There's class [`LispReader`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java) which contains nested class [`MapReader`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L1257) that is responsible for reading map literals. It's method `invoke` reads Clojure forms between `{`, `}` symbols and returns a map (*of Clojure forms*) by [calling](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L1263) [`RT.map`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L1562) method.
2. `RT.map` [calls](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L1567) [`PersistentHashMap.createWithCheck`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java#L61) where actual check for duplicated keys [is performed](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java#L66-L68). Since we're building map of *Clojure forms* the check will trigger even if there are two same forms that evaluate to different values (like in your example).
3. Evaluation of all Clojure forms is made in [`Compiler`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) class, in particular map forms are evaluated within it's nested class [`MapExpr`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3009). It's method [`eval`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L3019-L3024) evaluates map's keys and values and again builds persistent map using `RT.map`. So check for duplicated keys will be performed against evaluated values as well, that's why the following code will also fail:

```
(let [x :foo y :foo]
  {x :bar y :baz}) ;; throws duplicated key exception
```

I'm not sure why authors decided to perform check for duplicated keys on both map of forms and map of values. Probably, it's some kind of "fail fast strategy": such implementation will report about errors early at compilation stage (eventhough there may be false positives) and this check won't be deffered to the runtime.

Comment: Winner of a reply!

Comment: I think you answered your own question re why the check is in both places - the reader builds a map (which might have duplicate keys) and the evaluated map might also have duplicate keys.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you @OlegTheCat

Answer (score 4):

*Everything* produced by the reader is unevaluated. That's a main idea behind the reader: It reads forms as data with minimal-to-no interpretation. The reader gives the unevaluated map to the compiler.

The reader works by building the map up incrementally via assoc or conj. However, in the past, this approach would have produced an even stranger result for your code: `{(str (rand-int 5)) "goodbye"}`. That is, normal assoc-rules would apply: Last key-value-pair added wins. Folks ran in to this problem, so now the reader performs a `contains?` check before adding values incrementally.

This article discusses Lisp-style readers in a bit more detail: http://calculist.org/blog/2012/04/17/homoiconicity-isnt-the-point/

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that the reader doesn't evaluate the map.

Remember that evaluation happens after reading.

From the [Clojure reader reference documentation](http://clojure.org/reference/reader):

> That said, most Clojure programs begin life as text files, and it is the task of the reader to parse the text and produce the data structure the compiler will see. This is not merely a phase of the compiler. The reader, and the Clojure data representations, have utility on their own in many of the same contexts one might use XML or JSON etc.
>
> One might say the reader has syntax defined in terms of characters, and the Clojure language has syntax defined in terms of symbols, lists, vectors, maps etc. The reader is represented by the function read, which reads the next form (not character) from a stream, and returns the object represented by that form.

The evaluator needs the unevaluated map to walk through it and evaluate its keys and values.  If that map has the same form more than once as a key it is an invalid map literal.

You can use the `hash-map` function instead

```
(hash-map (rand-int 5) "hello"
          (rand-int 5) "goodbye")`.
```

Note that the resulting map may have one or two keys depending on whether the keys are distinct.

If you want to enforce two keys do sth. like

```
(zipmap (distinct (repeatedly #(rand-int 5)))
        ["hello" "goodbye"])
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer @leon-grapenthin

Comment: @stuartrexking Thanks, please reconsider accepting it. The answer you have accepted relies on undocumented implementation details which are subject to change and doesn't touch the language design aspect which is critical to answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to the question about the reader, but a safer way to construct this hash-map would be to ensure the keys are different. For example:

```
(let [[k1 k2] (shuffle (range 5))] 
  {k1 "hello" k2 "goodbye"})
```

Comment: Not efficient for large N, has O(N) complexity, should be O(1).

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Where does your requirement come from?

Comment: Efficiency. If generating two distinct random numbers in a range from 0-N has linear complexity O(N), then the algorithm introduces unnecessary overhead to the problem.

Comment: @leon This example is not optimized for large numbers, since the OP did not require that. It is not incorrect. However, what is the complexity of your example for `n` key/values? Since there is randomness   in play I'm not so sure. How is that `O(1)` anyway?

Comment: The above example avoids generating duplicates and removing them later. One could argue it is more efficient in the case where you need close or equal number to n key/vals for n in the expression `(range n)`.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Anyway, thanks for bringing up complexity. This got me thinking about the complexity of your code. I wonder how you can claim O(1). I guess the complexity has to be expressed in two or three variables (the amount of key/vals, the number `5` lifted to a variable and the chance distribution of duplicates, where in some cases your example is more efficient and in some cases mine if more efficient. I asked about the complexity of your example in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692742/complexity-of-clojures-distinct
Not so thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Let `n` be the amount of keys to be generated randomly from a pool of `0 .. m-1` numbers. The expected number of draws in your algorithm then becomes n×(Hn−Hn−j). More details here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2022030/391129. `O(1)` is clearly wrong. Only for values `n << m` it approaches `O(n)`.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin On the other hand, the above algorithm always performs in `O(n)` time. Note that `Collection.shuffle` is `O(m)`, `m` being the size of the pool, and taking the first `n` items from it is `O(n)` which makes `O(m + n)`. Because `n <= m` we have at most `O(2m)` which is just `O(n)`. So, the above algorithm is `O(n)`, where your algorithm is at best `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Of course I am referring to N as the exclusive upper bound of the random interval, not the number of keys. Your solution relies on generating all integers between 0<=i<N which has a linear complexity of O(N). I have ignored the complexity of shuffling which makes it even more complex as you state. If you replace 5 with a large number in both your and my example you will quickly notice the difference.

Comment: You have to take into account the number of keys `n` and the upper bound of the interval `m`. When `n` is near `m`, the above example performs better (in general, not in this concrete case).  Just look at the chart here:
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692742/complexity-of-clojures-distinct-randomly-generated-stream
Also please read:
- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021884/time-complexity-of-variation-on-coupons-collector-problem
- http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66236/what-is-the-complexity-of-a-variation-of-the-coupon-collectors-problem

Comment: I took into account the number of keys: `2`.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin In that case the expected amount of generated random numbers is `2.25`, slightly more than `n = 2`.

Comment: What are you implying?