# Complexity of Clojure's distinct + randomly generated stream

Tags: clojure, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of an expression

```
(doall (take n (distinct stream)))
```

where `stream` is a lazily generated (possibly infinite) collection with duplicates?

I guess this partially depends on the amount or chance of duplicates in `stream`? What if `stream` is `(repeatedly #(rand-int m)))` where  `m >= n`?

My estimation:

For every element in the resulting list there has to be at least one element realized from the stream. Multiple if the stream has duplicates. For every iteration there is a set lookup and/or insert, but since those are near constant time we get at least: `O(n*~1) = O(n)` and then some complexity for the duplicates. My intuition is that the complexity for the duplicates can be neglected too, but I'm not sure how to formalize this. For example, we cannot just say it is `O(n*k*~1)` = `O(n)` for some constant `k` since there is not an obvious maximum number `k` of duplicates we could encounter in the stream.

Let me demonstrate the problem with some data:

```
(defn stream [upper distinct-n]
  (let [counter (volatile! 0)]
    (doall (take distinct-n
                 (distinct
                  (repeatedly (fn []
                                (vswap! counter inc)
                                (rand-int upper))))))
    @counter))

(defn sample [times-n upper distinct-n]
  (->> (repeatedly times-n
                  #(stream upper distinct-n))
       frequencies
       (sort-by val)
       reverse))

(sample 10000 5 1) ;; ([1 10000])
(sample 10000 5 2) ;; ([2 8024] [3 1562] [4 334] [5 66] [6 12] [8 1] [7 1])
(sample 10000 5 3) ;; ([3 4799] [4 2898] [5 1324] [6 578] [7 236] [8 87] [9 48] [10 14] [11 10] [14 3] [12 2] [13 1])
(sample 10000 5 3) ;; ([3 4881] [4 2787] [5 1359] [6 582] [7 221] [8 107] [9 39] [10 12] [11 9] [12 1] [17 1] [13 1])
(sample 10000 5 4) ;; ([5 2258] [6 1912] [4 1909] [7 1420] [8 985] [9 565] [10 374] [11 226] [12 138] [13 89] [14 50] [15 33] [16 16] [17 9] [18 8] [20 5] [19 1] [23 1] [21 1])
(sample 10000 5 5) ;; ([8 1082] [9 1055] [7 1012] [10 952] [11 805] [6 778] [12 689] [13 558] [14 505] [5 415] [15 387] [16 338] [17 295] [18 203] [19 198] [20 148] [21 100] [22 96] [23 72] [24 53] [25 44] [26 40] [28 35] [27 31] [29 19] [30 16] [31 15] [32 13] [35 10] [34 6] [33 6] [42 3] [38 3] [45 3] [36 3] [37 2] [39 2] [52 1] [66 1] [51 1] [44 1] [41 1] [50 1] [60 1] [58 1])
```

Note that for the last sample the number of iterations `distinct` can go up to `66`, although the chance is small. 
Also notice that for increasing `n` in `(sample 10000 n n)` the most likely number of realized elements from the stream seems to go up more than linearly.

This chart illustrates the number of realized elements from the input (most common occurance from 10000 samples) in `(doall (take n (repeatedly #(rand-int m)))` for various numbers of `n` and `m`.

[image: data]

For completeness, here is the code I used to generate the chart:

```
(require '[com.hypirion.clj-xchart :as c])

(defn most-common [times-n upper distinct-n]
  (->> (repeatedly times-n
                   #(stream upper distinct-n))
       frequencies
       (sort-by #(- (val %)))
       ffirst))

(defn series [m]
  {(str "m = " m)
   (let [x (range 1 (inc m))]
     {:x x
      :y (map #(most-common 10000 m %)
              x)})})

(c/view
 (c/xy-chart
  (merge (series 10)
         (series 25)
         (series 50)
         (series 100))
  {:x-axis {:title "n"}
   :y-axis {:title "realized"}}))
```

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4933

Comment: @BlackBear Thanks. I know where to find the source. I elaborated on my question.

Comment: @ClojureMostly, no that is not true, true is: for every element in the resulting list, there has to be at least an iteration over all elements that come behind that element in the resulting list

Comment: @ClojureMostly That was poorly expressed by me. What I meant was: "at least one element realized from the stream".

Comment: @ClojureMostly best and worstcase do not need probability theory at all. The avarage case will need that, but only stuff that you learn in high school, but by the way, that does'nt look like O(n) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is known as the [Coupon collectors problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) and the expected number of elements is given by just summing up m/m + m/(m-1) ... until you have your n items:

```
(defn general-coupon-collector-expect
  "n: Cardinality of resulting set (# of uniuque coupons to collect)
   m: Cardinality of set to draw from (#coupons that exist)"
  [n m]
  {:pre [(<= n m)]}
  (double (apply + (mapv / (repeat m) (range m (- m n) -1)))))
(general-coupon-collector-expect 25 25)
;; => 95
;; This generates the data for you plot:
(for [x (range 10 101 5)]
  (general-coupon-collector-expect x 100))
```

Worst case will be infinite. Best case will be just N. Average case is O(N log N). This ignores the complexity of checking if an element has already been drawn. In practice it is Log_32 N for clojure sets (which is used in `distinct`).

Comment: please see my answere below, worst and best case complexity is certainly wrong

Comment: You express the complexity in the number of realized elements from the stream. But we don't know this number beforehand. That number is a dependent on a chance distribution. "Also notice that for increasing n in (sample 10000 n n) the most likely number of realized elements from the stream seems to go up more than linearly."

Comment: @MichielBorkent for best and worst case we don't need to care about a chance distribution

Comment: because best and worst case is about special cases, just take the single worst case that is possible and calculate the complexity for that explicitly.

Comment: worstcase: ```(doall (take n (distinct stream)))``` with ```(def stream (repeat 0))``` so running that will never terminate. so O(∞)

Comment: @ClojureMostly bestcase: time to verify that a list is distinct = (n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-n)=(n-1)(n-2)/2. take first element and comare it against the rest of the list, take second element and compare it against the rest of the list etc.... There is no implementation shortcut possible, this is just the amount of actions it takes...

Comment: @ClojureMostly This problem is similar but not equal to the Coupon collectors problem. We do not have to draw n predefined coupons. The requirement is more relaxed here: as long as the n draws are different, we're happy. So I think we're close!

Comment: I understand Coupon's collector has only one variable `n` where you draw coupons from a set of `n` until you've seen all `n` coupons. That is a variation of this problem but not the same problem, it's not even a relaxation. I expect the complexity to depend on `n` (the size of the subset) as well as `m` (the size of the entire pool).

Comment: @ClojureMostly `m/m + m/(n-1) ...` until you have your n items", this should probably read as `m/m + m/(m-1) ...`

Comment: How I understand it informally: The expected amount of draws the first time is always `1`. The second time the chance on a correct draw is `(n - 1)/n`, so the expected amount of draws becomes `n/(n-1)`. Repeat until we have `n` elements. 
Since this seems to be same as your code, I accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The final line of `general-coupon-collector-expect` is probably better as `(* m (apply + (mapv (comp / double) (range m (- m n) -1))))`.

Comment: If `m` is much larger than `n`, the solution is `O(n)`. So `O(n log n)` is not a tight bound (not big theta). A tight bound must involve `m`.

Comment: @Thumbnail Correct

Comment: @ClojureMostly Worst case complexity of infinity implies a broken random generator.

Answer (score 0):

While I aggree with ClojureMostly [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694013/2402383), that a lookup in a lazy sequence is O(1) if you iterate over the list in order. I disagree with best and worst case complexity.

In general `(doall (take n (distinct stream)))` is not guaranteed to finish at all so worst case time complexity is obivously O(infinite). Even if the stream is generated randomly, it might be identicall to  let's say `(repeat 0)`

Best case complexity would be either O(1) for n<=1 (you do not need to any check for beeing distinct on a list of length 0 or 1)

If you say n needs to  be greater then 1 it will be O((n-1)(n-2)/2) (for a list that is allready distinct to check you need to iterate for each element over all the elements that come after this element. that will be `(n-1) + (n-2)+...+(n-n) = (n-1)(n-2)/2`. This is a slight deviation from what [Carl Friedrich Gauß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Early_years)
, a german mathematician, dicovered while beeing in primary school)

Note that best and worstcase is not dependent on how the stream is generated. However this will be important if you are interested in average complexity

Average complexity:
Let's say you genereate the stream with `(repeatedly #(rand-int m))`, which means it is evenly distributed.
Average complexity will then be best case complexity O plus the expected amount of duplicates in the first n elements of the stream (that is n/m ) times the expected amount of additional lookups in stream to find another value, that has not been in the resulting list yet. This will be (i/m), wehre i is the index of the current element in the resulting list.

Because stream is a evenly distributed random sequence, i is expected to be evenly distributed as well, so it will on average equal n/2. there we go:
`O((n-1)(n-2)/2 + ( n/m * n/2m))`

Comment: I'm interested in the average complexity.

Comment: `(n-1)(n-2)/2` is quadratic, so I don't get how you arrive at `O(n-1)`. In the best case, the input is already distinct, then the complexity will still be `O(n)` since you have to realize `n` elements of the stream.

Comment: @MichielBorkent , I added the calculation for average complexity. as you noted ```O(n-1) ``` was a typo. You're right that in the best case the list is allready distinct. Time to verify that: take every element of the list (n) and compare it to all the elements that come after it (n-1 for the first one, n-2 for the second one).

Comment: @ClojureMostly please read my answer carfully, I do not say each time the whole sequence is iterate, I say for every element, all elements after that element need to be iterated.

Comment: After accumulating a *set* of `n` elements from a sequence, you can check whether a successive offered element is distinct from them in almost *constant* time (`O(log32 n)` in persistent clojure hash sets). This is what core `distinct` does [internally](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4825). The `(n - 1)(n - 2)/2` factor should be `n` or `n - 1`, depending on how you code it.

Comment: @zabeltech If worst case complexity is O(infinite) your random number generator is broken.